# oci_excute error when try to upload file php

Tags: php, oracle, blob

This code should upload a blob file image to oracle database. While I try to use the following code, the variable `$objExecute` produces an error!
Please help to fix this.

```
$error= $_FILES['Image_assigned']['error'];
$objConnect = oci_connect("jab","jabee","j-windows7/XE");
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($objConnect, OCI_D_LOB);
$strSQL ="insert into SS_USERS_PIC (SYSUID,PICTURE) values (F_SS_GET_AUTO_ID('SYSUID','PICTURE') , EMPTY_BLOB())  RETURNING ImageFile INTO :BLOBDATA " .")";

// $strSQL='insert into mybtab (blobid, blobdata) values (:myblobid, EMPTY_BLOB()) returning blobdata into :blobdata';
$objParse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);
oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':BLOBDATA', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
$objExecute = oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);
$lob->savefile($_FILES['Image_assigned']['tmp_name']);
$errorCode= $_FILES['Image_assigned']['error'];

if ($objExecute)
{
    oci_commit($objConnect); 
    echo "Copy/Upload Complete<br>";
}
else
{
    oci_rollback($objConnect); 
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
    echo "Copy/Upload is not Complete";
}
```

Comment: _$objExecute produce error_ Would you mind terribly sharing the actual error message with us please

Comment: that is right , but how to catch error message ?

Comment: No, what is the full error message

Comment: When in doubt with PHP OCI8, check the sections on error handling and LOBs in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  function upload($operation){

if(!empty($_FILES['Image_assigned']['name']) &&  !($_FILES['Image_assigned']['error']))
{
    $uploadedFile = '';
    if(!empty($_FILES["Image_assigned"]["type"]))
    {
        $fileName = time().'_'.$_FILES['Image_assigned']['name'];
        $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["Image_assigned"]["name"]);
        $file_extension = end($temporary);
        $blobdata = file_get_contents($_FILES['Image_assigned']['tmp_name']);   
    if((($_FILES["hard_file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["Image_assigned"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["Image_assigned"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && in_array($file_extension, $valid_extensions))
        {
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['Image_assigned']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = "uploads/".$fileName;
        }
    }


    $objConnect = oci_connect("[username]","[password]","[hostname]/[instnce_name]");
    $lob = oci_new_descriptor($objConnect, OCI_D_LOB);
 if ($operation=='ADD'){
    $strSQL ="insert into [TableName] (PICTURE) values ( EMPTY_BLOB())  RETURNING PICTURE INTO :BLOBDATA ";
    $objParse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);

}
    // *************************************
    oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':BLOBDATA', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
    try
    {
        $objExecute = oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);
        $lob->savefile($_FILES['Image_assigned']['tmp_name']);  
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $err = $e->getMessage();
    }
    if($objExecute)
    {
        oci_commit($objConnect); 
        echo "Copy/Upload Complete<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        oci_rollback($objConnect); 
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
        echo "Copy/Upload is not Complete";
    }

    oci_free_descriptor($lob);
    oci_free_statement($objParse);
    oci_close($objConnect);
}
```

}